# Missing Gulp Events in 4.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

In Gulp 3.x there was the ability to tie into its event system with Orchestrator to do things when a task starts or a task ends by using the `task_start`, `task_stop` or `stop` listeners.

**Example:**

```
gulp.on('task_start', (e) => {
  // Task event information
  console.log(e);
});
```

It seems Gulp has removed Orchestrator and replaced it with a new library called Undertaker. However, I can't find any reference to an internal API event system now in Gulp.

Is there any way to achieve these type of events in a custom Gulp plugin still in version 4.x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

use `gulp.on('start', callback)`, `gulp.on('stop', callback)` and `gulp.on('error', callback)`

---

[Undertaker](https://github.com/gulpjs/undertaker) inherits from [EventEmitter](https://github.com/Olical/EventEmitter) library. (you can find its API docs [here](https://github.com/Olical/EventEmitter/blob/master/docs/api.md))

in Undertaker, [this](https://github.com/gulpjs/undertaker/blob/master/lib/helpers/createExtensions.js) is the file responsible for emitting the above cited event. You can check it out to see what's being passed to the callback function.

**PS**: Since version 4 release, Gulp documentation has become a bit of a mess, I'm struggling with this too, finding conflicting docs between 3 and 4, with no clear deprecation warnings with version 3 docs. So checking the source code for undocumented parts of the API can be of a great help.

Comment: Thanks, Halim. This was very helpful!